# Does a parent rerender trigger its custom hook to be "re-created"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to get a basic understanding for custom hooks. I currently have a `parent` component and a custom hook to handle *some* of its logic. My custom hook looks like :

```
export const useTrip = () => {
    const origin = useSelector((store) =>
        store.trip.origin
    )
    const destination = useSelector((store) =>
        store.trip.destination
    )
    const [waypoints, setWaypoints] = useState([])
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        expensiveFunction()
    }, [origin, destination])
    const getMidpoints = (value) => {
       ...
       setWaypoints(result)
    }
    console.log("this triggers way more times than expected")
    const expensiveFunction = () => {
       ...
       setValue(result)
    }
    return { getMidpoints, waypoints, value }
}
```

I have a lot more stuff in my custom hook but it seems that my custom hook is "re-rendering" too many times, and as I see with my `console.log` Is there a reason why this custom hook is being rerendered?

EDIT: after more testing, it seems that if the dependencies of my  `useEffect` hook change, the entire custom hook is reran, and I see my `console.log` line again. Is this proper behavior for a custom hook? Or am i using it incorrectly

Comment: Not sure how your redux store is updated, but the `React.useEffect()` will run whenever the given dependencies change. Make the dependency array an empty array and it should only run once. If you still see multiple re-renders, even with the dependency array empty, you know whatever is using your custom hook is what is running multiple times. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Comment: redux store is update by dispatching reducers. but i want to know if whether a parent component will trigger the custom hook to "re-create" itself.

Comment: I was saying you do not show how the reducers are called. Depending on how the store changes, it could be calling your method multiple times. Also if you are using React version 18, the `React.useEffect` will run twice. It is to prevent poor use of the `useEffect` and to allow for reusable states.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the function of the custom hook to be run *always*, or *whenever react likes to run it*.

Only the functions passed to the `useEffect` calls inside the hook might be called less often *(i.e. if theis dependencies change)*.

So, **yes, it is ok** that your `console.log` inside the hook is called so many times *(assuming that it is correct that the main function is called so many times)*.

#### A mental model

You can think of it (as a mental model) like the whole content of your custom hook would be just
inside your main function, e.g.:

```
const useMyHook = () => {
    console.log('this line was ivoked');
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('useEffect was ivoked');
    });
};

const Main = ( props ) => {
    useMyHook();
    return <>nothing</>
};
```

behaves pretty much the same as:

```
const Main = ( props ) => {
    
    console.log('this line was ivoked');
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('useEffect was ivoked');
    });
    
    return <>nothing</>
};
```

#### How to understand hook calls

You are not supposed to rely on when and how often the hook-function itself is run, instead you
should only rely on the guarantees that react gives you, like:

- *some state is guaranteed to be up-to-date if ...*, or
- *this useEffect function will be invoked if ...*.
- ...

#### Smaller hooks

You said *"I have a lot more stuff in my custom hook ..."*. I suggest to break your custom hook down into smaller custom hooks.